# Método getValuetAt tipo de arreglos incompatible

Tags: java, java-swing, arraylist

tengo un detalle usando `ArrayList` de Java. Estoy intentando implementar un AbstractTableModel para crear métodos que se ejecutan en un JTable (siguiendo la doc de Oracle). Sin embargo, trabajando con `getValueAt()`, tengo el siguiente error: `Array type expected rowIndex – the row whose value is to be queried`

Aqui es donde creo los datos "dummies" para testear.

```
public class Data {
  public List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
  
  public Data(){
    Course course1 = new Course("Matematicas",8);
    Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("HSHG223", "Alberto Coyote");
    CourseTeacher courseteachers1 = new CourseTeacher(course1, teacher1);
    Student student1 = new Student("HSG223", "Juan Perez", "12/12/21", courseteachers1);
    students.add(student1);
  }
}
```

El codigo inicial:

```
String[] columnStudents = {"Nombre", "Materia", "Calificacion", "Materia","Calificacion", "DNI", "Profe"};
ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();

public CRUDStudent(List<Student> students){
    list = new ArrayList<Student>(students);
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return list.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
}
```

Intente casteando el String para ver si se podia arreglar, sin embargo, el error me dice que no se puede castear un arreglo:

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
  String[] row = (String[]) list.get(rowIndex);
  return row[columnIndex];
}
```

Alguna manera de que AbstractTableModel reconozca el Array y el ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolver mi duda, la escribo por si a alguien le puede servir:

Me explico, el problema era que estaba intentando acceder a un objeto Student por medio de `list.get(rowIndex)`. Es decir, al ser una un objeto que representa las filas debes tomar sus valores por medio de sus getters.
`list.get(rowIndex).getStudentName();`

En mi caso es un objeto y tienes que acceder por medio del método sobreescrito que es `getValueAt()`, en mi caso lo modifique de esta manera para que funcionara:

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex){
      case 0:
        return this.list.get(rowIndex).getStudentDNI();
      case 1:
        return this.list.get(rowIndex).getName();
      case 2:
        return this.list.get(rowIndex).getDate();
      case 3:
        return this.list.get(rowIndex).getCourseteacher();
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```